# Embeded Images CID in Mailchimp

Tags: image, embed, mailchimp, newsletter

I am using mailchimp to send my companies newsletter. In outlook the images of my newsletter dont show up when i open them. I have to unblock them.

Now i got a newsletter of another company and their pictures show up. They use cid to embed the images into the newsletter. Is this possible in mailchimp and are there any disadvantages of this options?

Thanks for your help.